# How to dynamically enter a from email address in smtpclient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am currently using SMTPClient to send an email from a web form in asp.net. I have EnableSsl set to false and I do not understand how it authenticates my email but cannot automatically enter it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP host doesn't authenticate the from field in an email passed to it, it authenticates the account that generates the request to send the email. You can provide any valid email address as the sender. If your asp.net app is configured for windows authentication, you could try to get access to `MembershipUser` to get the email. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx